# Android IntentService SMS Queue Handing

Tags: android, android-intent, sms

I'm writing an Android App that receives text messages from a server via HTTP. I have a button on my App labeled "Poll". When I press this button, the App Polls the a server via HTTP and fetches some text messages.

These texts messages are to be sent out via SMS. What I would like to happen, is for there to be a background queue where these messages are added to. As soon as a message is added to the queue, the queue must immediately be attempted to be "flushed" (i.e. send all pending SMSs over the network). If the sending fails, the App must retry by itself every 60 seconds indefinitely.

What is the best way to achieve this? I guess I'm looking for some form of implementation where an IntentService has a timer that expires every 60 seconds, but can be forced to be expired on demand once a new text message comes in.

I'm ok regarding SMS functionality, as I've been following this guide: http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android

It's just the queue handing I need some help with.

Any help is appreciated, thanks